# XCode4 Building Problem - Code Signing Identity Ad Hoc missing

Tags: iphone, xcode4, identity, signing, ad-hoc-distribution

trying to build an ad hoc distribution with Xcode 4.
Consider that my project.xcodeproj was created with a very old version of Xcode.
Now Looking around  at Build Setting I cannot find Code Signing Identity Ad Hoc as shown into attached image:

[image]

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@freedev I just wrote a [blog post detailing the ad hoc process in Xcode 4](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1237) that should help you.

Comment: Including a link is helpful, but you should include at least part of the text in your post, especially that last bit about disabling code signing in the Build Settings.

Answer (score 0):

[You might want to check this document out: Xcode 4 transition guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Project and build settings are now at the top of the project files.